# How to resize button without constraints in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am currently trying to resize a button without using any constraints.
I'd like to use this method because my view controller is getting very complex and using constraints would be long and hard to do without messing everything else.

I've heard about `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` but I don't really know how this works.

I would like to do something like this:

```
self.button.frame.size.height += 20
```

I would be glad to know if someone can help me out.

Comment: The answer depends on the context. If you just want to position the button manually, don't autolayout it and assign `frame` as you please to set the absolute size and position (e.g., in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`). On the other hand, if you need autolayout content to be aware of the button, just use the constraints.

Comment: @Arkku I didn't even know we could use "frame" like this, thanks